# How to Parse the XML response of a URI in ansible

Tags: ansible

There is a code which call the web services of an application.

```
 - uri:
         url: http://10.164.52.61:8080/ems/v74/ws/customer.ws?customerRefId=f4XXXb15d69c3
         method: GET
         content_as_json: true
         password: admin
         user: admin
         validate_certs: no
         return_content: yes
         HEADER_Cookie: "{{login.set_cookie}}"
        register: customerId

      - debug:
          var: customerId.content
```

The sample response is

```
"customerId.content": "<listResponse type=\"customer\" count=\"1\"><instance customerId=\"28\" name=\"abc\" customerRefId=\"xyz\" refId1=\"12\" type=\"org\" enabled=\"true\" phone=\"\" fax=\"\" billingZip=\"\" billingAddress=\"\" billingCity=\"\" billingCountry=\"\" billingState=\"\" vendor=\"1\" defaultEmail=\"test\" defaultContactName=\"test\"/></listResponse>"
```

I want to access the list response in my next block of code. Like i need just the value of "customerId". How this can be achieved using anisble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no XML support in Ansible out of the box.
You can use regex filters to make some simple searches in your XML data.
In your example:

```
- debug: msg="{{ customerId.content | regex_findall('customerId=\"(\d+)\"') }}"
```

Will search for `customerId=\"<number>\"` strings and return a list of numbers in quotes.

Update: fully working example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    myvar: "<listResponse type=\"customer\" count=\"1\"><instance customerId=\"28\" name=\"abc\" customerRefId=\"xyz\" refId1=\"12\" type=\"org\" enabled=\"true\" phone=\"\" fax=\"\" billingZip=\"\" billingAddress=\"\" billingCity=\"\" billingCountry=\"\" billingState=\"\" vendor=\"1\" defaultEmail=\"test\" defaultContactName=\"test\"/></listResponse>"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ myvar | regex_findall('customerId=\"(\d+)\"') }}"
```

I use `ansible 2.1.1.0`.

Comment: I had this same problem and instead of getting any value i am getting what is mentioned in msg. Like for this case it is "msg": "{{customerId.content | regex_findall(\"customerId=\\\"(\\d+)\\\"\")}}" . It is the result of this particular task.

Comment: I've updated the answer with fully working example, please inspect it.

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to sebaszw's answer, however doesn't require the xml response to be written to a file, instead storing it in a variable.

```
- uri:
    url: http://10.164.52.61:8080/ems/v74/ws/customer.ws?customerRefId=f4XXXb15d69c3
    method: GET
    content_as_json: true
    password: admin
    user: admin
    validate_certs: no
    return_content: yes
    HEADER_Cookie: "{{login.set_cookie}}"
  register: customerId

- xml:
    xmlstring: "{{customerId.content}}"
    xpath: /listResponse/instance
    content: attribute
  register: instance_attributes

- debug:
    var: instance_attributes.matches.0.instance.customerId
```

Comment: Looks a lot cleaner

Answer (score 2):

From Ansible 2.4 you can do this:

```
- get_url:
    url: http://10.164.52.61:8080/ems/v74/ws/customer.ws?customerRefId=f4XXXb15d69c3
    dest: ./response.xml
    url_password: admin
    url_user: admin
    validate_certs: no
    headers:
      Cookie: "{{login.set_cookie}}"

- xml:
    path: ./response.xml
    xpath: /listResponse/instance
    content: attribute
  register: instance_attributes

- debug:
    var: instance_attributes.matches.0.instance.customerId
```

Comment: FYI: documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/xml_module.html

Answer (score 1):

I just added XML parsing support in the uri module because I needed it too.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/53045

Just like the JSON support, it will return an 'xml' key with a dictionary consisting of the XML content for the convenience of accessing the data in the payload.

Your example would look like this:

```
 - uri:
     url: http://10.164.52.61:8080/ems/v74/ws/customer.ws?customerRefId=f4XXXb15d69c3
     method: GET
     password: admin
     user: admin
     validate_certs: no
     HEADER_Cookie: "{{login.set_cookie}}"
    register: customerId

  - debug:
      var: customerId.xml.listResponse.instance['@customerId']
```

The output in customerId.xml would be:

```
{
    'listResponse': {
        '@type': 'customer',
        '@count', '1',
        'instance': {
            '@customerId': '28',
            '@name': 'abc'
            '@customerRefId': 'xyz',
            '@refId1': '12',
            '@type': 'org',
            '@enabled': 'true',
            '@phone': '',
            '@fax': '',
            '@billingZip': '',
            '@billingAddress': '',
            '@billingCity': '',
            '@billingCountry': '',
            '@billingState': '',
            '@vendor': '1',
            '@defaultEmail': 'test',
            '@defaultContactName': 'test'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its worth looking at [ansible-xml](https://github.com/cmprescott/ansible-xml) for this. It's not part of Ansible but its a super useful module for parsing xml, it uses the `lxml` Python library under the hood.

Comment: It has been merged: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html

Answer (score 0):

As this was reasonably complex getting this to work I thought I'd post my Ansible - XML parameters for parsing a SOAP response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <S:Body xmlns:ns2="http://ws.coverity.com/v9">
      <ns2:getLdapServerDomainsResponse>
        <return>
            <name>soapui_test</name>
        </return>
      </ns2:getLdapServerDomainsResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The trick was getting namespaces and xpath right. Also as I wanted the actual name I needed `content: text`

```
- name: Extract the name from the SOAP
  xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ ldap_response.content }}"
    xpath: "/S:Envelope/S:Body/ns2:getLdapServerDomainsResponse/return/name"
    namespaces:
      S: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      SOAP-ENV: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      ns2: "http://ws.coverity.com/v9"
    content: text
  register: ldap_name
```

I still don't understand why the xpath section at the end doesn't work with `.../ns2:return/ns2:name` as the [Ansible - XML docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html#examples) example suggests. The above fills `ldap_name` with (simplified):

```
"ldap_name": {
    "matches": [
        {
            "name": "soapui_test"
        }
    ],
}
```